# How to add custom images as UIApplicationShortcutIcon for UIApplicationShortcutItem?

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

How to add custom images as `UIApplicationShortcutIcon` for `UIApplicationShortcutItem`? which is similar like photos `UIApplicationShortcutItem` in Photos/Message app for most recent.Because all icon are Created an icon from a custom image.The provided image named will be loaded from the app's bundle and will be masked to conform to the system-defined icon style.So how can i get color image as `UIApplicationShortcutIcon` programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can add short cut icons from app delegate also.Here ***img_editProduct*** and ***img_Classifieds*** are custom images added in .**xcassests** file

```
- (void)shortcutsWithIcon
{
    @try 
    {
       UIApplicationShortcutIcon *icon1 = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:@"img_editProduct"];
       UIApplicationShortcutIcon *icon2 = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:@"img_Classifieds"];

       UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem *item1 = [[UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem alloc]initWithType:@"com.3dtouchApp.postAnItem" localizedTitle:@"Post an Item" localizedSubtitle:@"Add new product for sale" icon:icon1 userInfo:nil];
       UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem *item2 = [[UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem alloc]initWithType:@"com.3dtouchApp.LatestAds" localizedTitle:@"Latest Ads" localizedSubtitle:@"View top recent Ads" icon:icon2 userInfo:nil];
       NSArray *items = @[item2, item1];

       [UIApplication sharedApplication].shortcutItems = items;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }
}


 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   if (self.window.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable)
    {
       [self shortcutsWithIcon];
         if ([item.type isEqualToString:@"com.3dtouchApp.postAnItem"])
         {
           ***//Code for launch your screen***
         }

         if ([item.type isEqualToString:@"com.3dtouchApp.LatestAds"])
         {
            ***//code for launch your screen***
         }
    }
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Don't use an emoji in place of a template icon. Emojis don't align
>   properly when the text is right-aligned. Also, emojis are full color,
>   whereas template icons should be monochromatic. You can choose from
>   among the many system-provided template icons or you can create a
>   custom template icon. For detailed guidance on icon sizes, padding,
>   and positioning, download Home Screen Quick Action Icon Template from
>   https://developer.apple.com/design/downloads/Quick-Action-Guides.zip.
>   To learn more about designing a template icon, see Template Icons.

As per above text, I dont think there is no way to display coloured icon. May be we will get in future update.